# Strange behavior when using HTTP Range along with OkHttp

Tags: android, http, http-headers, okhttp

I'm using **OkHttp** on my project for downloading a binary file on separate chunks using the `Range` HTTP header.

Say I want to download a file with content length of 9968738 bytes. Splitting it on equally size chunks with the exception of the last chunk request, where I force it to get all that's left:

`Range: bytes=9138008-9968737` <-- request for last chunk

Despite I make a request for this range though, the response I'm getting is like:

`Content-Range: bytes 9138008-9968735/9968738`

I tried the same request with cURL pointing to the samer URL and I get the *expected response*.

Is this an issue from OkHttp or my misunderstanding of the HTTP Range header?

Comment: Consider using a tool like Charlesproxy or OkHttp interceptors to see exactly what is being sent to the server, and exactly what is being returned. If OkHttp and cURL are giving you different results, something strange is happening.